# How to get a substring javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a String like `var foo = 'foo {{Email18}}'`. But the digit part is variable or unknown.

I need to get the subString `{{Email18}}`.

I want to do something like `foo.search(/{{Email\d{1,}}}/)` which will return me `{{Email18}}`. How do I do that?

Comment: As a side note, the quantifier `+` is semantically equivalent to your quantifier `{1,}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** with regex `/{{Email\d{1,}}}/`

```js
var foo = 'foo {{Email18}}';

console.log(
  foo.match(/{{Email\d{1,}}}/)[0]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a little string manipulation:

```
var str = "foo {{Email18}}";

function myFunction(arg) {
    return arg.toString().substr(arg.indexOf("{"), arg.lastIndexOf("}"));
}; 

var newStr = myFunction(str);
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I don't see the point of using a function here if you don't pass the string as a parameter.

Comment: @Aaron: Here you go! :)